# Corresponding verb for "system architect"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

In computer world, there is a position called "*architect*", like "*system architect*", "*solution architect*". What is the corresponding verb of *doing* it? E.g.,

> He was a system architect in our team. He *architected* the whole infrastructure for us.

**EDIT** This is a very *specific* question in *computer world*, so if you are not 100% clear what an "*application architect*" and an "*application designer*" does, and their differences, please refrain from answering the question.

Comment: *Design*, perhaps? That's what architects do.

Comment: [It is possible to use *architect* as a verb, although to many people it sounds ugly and jargonish.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/is-architect-a-verb-and-a-noun)  *Design* is a good choice, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence maybe should read

> He was a system architect **on** our team.

Usually, one would not say

> He *architected* the whole infrastructure for us.

but possibly

> He was *the architect of* the infrastructure.

in order of decreasing similarity to *architected*

> He *specified* the whole infrastructure for us.
>   He *outlined* the whole infrastructure for us.
>   He *designed* the whole infrastructure for us.
>   He *developed* the whole infrastructure for us.

From my experience, the person who is the architect is the one who *specifies* the flow of process and logic, not necessarily the one who *implements* the solution, but could also be.

For example, one can "*develop* an API", as in code it, and also "*develop* an API", as in an iterative process of specification.  Mutual understanding is necessary to tease out the intent of "develop".